# MVC 3 default edit won't work if I remove a field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a default MVC 3 project and created the default edit page for my model. If I don't touch it, everything work fine.

Now I wanted to remove one of the edit fields on the edit page (because I don't want the primary key to be editable). So I just changed the EditFor to a DisplayFor. Everything is sown correctly then, but if I want to save I get the following error:

> **DbUpdateConcurrencyException was unhandled by user code**
>
> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

In the edit action I can see, that my model class doesn't get the primary key anymore (it's 0) and so the update doesn't work.

```
// POST: /Weiterleitung/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Rufnummern_Weiterleitungen rufnummern_weiterleitungen)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(rufnummern_weiterleitungen).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(rufnummern_weiterleitungen);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

How can I avoid this error without showing every single field of my model as edit field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your POST action misses the Id because a DisplayFor<> doesn't render a HTML control and the value therefore is not posted back to your controller action. You can either pass the id to your action as a parameter (you then need to add that parameter to your Html.BeginForm()-call in the view and modify your Edit action accordingly) or you can add a HiddenFor<>-field that contains the id. A hidden field is passed on to the controller upon postback and should be recognized by the default binding handler that creates the `Rufnummern_Weiterleitungen` instance from the form values.

Comment: We tend to remove stuff that was autogenerated in views such as this `EditFor`, because we do not want user to edit the primary key. Indeed Dirk told the right thing: we just need to replace the `EditFor` with `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.YourPrimaryKey)`.

Answer (score 0):

Only edit fields (`<input>`, `<select>` and `<textare>` inside the `<form>`) are posted back to the server.

I advice against using your db entities directly in the views. Read why here:

http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/three-reasons-to-why-you-should-use-view-models/

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I am actually not a big fan of asp.net and MVC, so I stick with the default settings, less work for me. :)

Comment: Less work today, sure. But you'll regret it in a couple of months when you have to start adding workarounds.

Comment: It's just a small project. "Let me edit the one table from the browser", end of specs. :) But I will keep it in mind, if there will come a bigger MVC project.